# Get rid of directory (top level in portal)

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

In the azure portal I can see two directories, a "Default Directory" which stems from a project I was invited to and my actual directory. I do not require the "Default Directory" anymore and I always have to switch to my directory first when I log into the portal. Can I get rid of the "Default Directory"?

I am asking, because I want to enlarge a vhd disk. I read I can do this with the Azure PowerShell Module (http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2015/03/24/resizing-data-disks-in-the-cloud-on-microsoft-azure.aspx). However, when I execute the script there, I always end up using the "Default Directory". How can I switch to my directory in the Azure Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Default Directory is automatically created if you create a new Azure subscription. So, it sounds strange to me to get rid of the default directory. But anyway...

If you cannot delete a directory, you can at least disconnect your user account from that directory you do not want listed in the Azure portal.

There is an easy workaround if you just want the AAD disconnected from your account.

1. Create a new user in your AAD with global admin rights.
2. Log in at https://portal.office.com with the newly created user account and switch into the configuration to the active users. In that list remove your account that you usually use to log in to Azure Management Portal.
3. That’s it! (Of course the sub domain of the AAD still exists. But in your scenario this seems not be an issue.)
4. Tip: If you want for any chance access again to that AAD save the credentials from step 1.

A [complete guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pkirchner/2016/01/29/how-to-delete-an-azure-active-directory-connected-to-microsoft-online-services/) for this workaround is posted in my blog.